Anyone know how to get around this error Encountered an error 'getauthok ended in error'
The call to GETAUTHOK ended in error
Line of failure:
/ Get authentication token from Fedex  authToken = : clientId: clientSecret)
Httpresponse =getAuthToken(apiKey: clientid: clientsecret);
Working a creating fedex rest api program
for tracking
